# Center HTML Input Text Field Placeholder

Tags: html, css

How can I centre the input field's placeholder's alignment in a html form?

I am using the following code, but it doesn't work:

CSS ->

```
input.placeholder {
    text-align: center;
}
.emailField {
    top:413px;
    right:290px;
    width: 355px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    border: none;
    font-size: 17;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML ->

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" class="emailField" placeholder="support@socialpic.org" style="text-align: center" name="email" />
    <!<input type="submit" value="submit" />  
</form>
```

Comment: Not really an answer, but jQuery Mobile does this so you might want to look how they achieve it.

Comment: For me, your code works when you get rid of the `input.placeholder` bit. Aligning the text inside the input to center aligns the placeholder as well.

Answer (score 329, accepted):

If you want to change only the placeholder style, select the [`::placeholder` pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder)

```css
::placeholder {
   text-align: center; 
}

/* or, for legacy browsers */

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   text-align: center;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   text-align: center;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   text-align: center;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   text-align: center; 
}
```

Comment: This works fine for most input fields, but not for type date. Do you know how to also make it work for date?

Answer (score 118):

```
input{
   text-align:center;
}
```

is all you need.

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/LUrjJ/) in FF6. This method doesn't seem to be cross-browser compatible.

Your previous CSS was attempting to center the text of an input element which had a class of "placeholder".

Comment: I wan't to centre the placeholder as well as the text entered into the field

Comment: Yes. This is what this example does. The placeholder _is_ text in the field.

Comment: it doesn't work in the example. In the example, the placeholder is left aligned.

Comment: Beware, if you're using libraries such as Bootstrap or Semantic UI, you must add the style inline, i.e. `<input type="text" placeholder="Search..." style="text-align: right;">` for it to work. Or add `important!` to your CSS rule if you're using external files.

Comment: It looks like the problem you are having max_ is just an issue of browser compatibility. This works fine in most major browsers except Safari.

Answer (score 10):

you can use also this way to write css for placeholder

```
input::placeholder{
   text-align: center;
}

/* or, for legacy browsers */

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   text-align: center;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   text-align: center;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   text-align: center;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   text-align: center; 
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use set in a class like below and set to input text class

CSS:

```
 .place-holder-center::placeholder {
        text-align: center;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="place-holder-center">
```

Answer (score 7):

The HTML5 placeholder element can be styled for those browsers that accept the element, but in diferent ways, as you can see here: http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder-css.

But I don't believe that `text-align` will be interpreted by the browsers. At least on Chrome, this attribute is ignored. But you can always change other things, like `color`, `font-size`, `font-family` etc. I suggest you rethinking your design whether possible to remove this center behavior.

**EDIT**

If you really want this text centered, you can always use some jQuery code or plugin to simulate the placeholder behavior. Here is a sample of it: http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html.

This way the style will work:

```
input.placeholder {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can make like this:

```
    <center>
    <form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" class="emailField" placeholder="support@socialpic.org" style="text-align: center" name="email" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />  
</form>
    </center>
```

[Working CodePen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXEQPv)

Comment: Only this is working for me. Maybe styles added in HTML is given more priority or overriding all other styles.

Answer (score 3):

You can try like this :

```
input[placeholder] {
   text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**For vertically centering the placeholder:**

```
input::placeholder{
position:relative !important;
top:50% !important;
transform:translateY(-50%) !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #d0cdfa;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
}
:-moz-placeholder { 
 font-size:14px;
 color: #d0cdfa;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
}
::-moz-placeholder { 
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #d0cdfa; 
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
} 
:-ms-input-placeholder { 
 font-size: 14px; 
 color: #d0cdfa;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the code snippet below, you are selecting the placeholder inside your input, and any code placed inside will affect only the placeholder.

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
      text-align: center
}
```

Comment: This answer does not seem to offer anything different compared to the [Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15378182/2452869).

Comment: This answer does give a hint of how to change the placeholder of only one specific element as opposed to all placeholders. E.g. `.foo::-webkit-input-placeholder { … }`.