# Centering the text in the input field in jQueryMobile on iPhone

Tags: jquery-mobile

So, if you take a look at the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jb8Jx/) (I posted the code below for consistency) you will see that the input text is centered. However, if I visit the jsfiddle (and on my testing site) on my iPhone (iOS5) the text is just left-aligned. So, am wondering do you guys maybe know is this a know issue (googled - seems not) and do you know of a workaround.

css:

```
.centerText{
    text-align: center;
}​
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#popupLogin" ).popup( "open" );            
});​
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>    
    <section id="home" data-role="page">
        <header data-role="header">
            <h1>test page</h1>
        </header>

        <div data-role="popup" id="popupLogin" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all">
            <h3 class="centerText">Register free!</h3>
            <div class="popup">
                <form>                
                      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="centerText" placeholder="email" data-theme="a"/>
                      <button type="submit" data-theme="b">Sign me up</button>

                      <p class="centerText">
                          text1<br/>
                          text2<br/>
                          etc...<br/>
                      </p>                
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `<header data-role="header">` vs `<div data-role="header">`? I know it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: No, no particular reason whatsoever, but as you said, it doesn't make any diference, so am curious why do you ask?

Comment: I am able to replicate the behavior in Safari, 'email' is left aligned. When I click on the field, the new text is centered. So are you trying to center the placeholder or the text that is entered? It was just idle curiosity.

Comment: oh, you're right! It now turns out that I want to center the placeholder. Kudos for noticing this!

Comment: Right on! FYI I tested the jsFiddle on a iPhone just to check and it showed the Placeholder and the Text as centered, iOS 6.0.1

Comment: Great, so even though this is a minor thing, and as it seems it is OS dependant I'm wondering if there is some kind of a "css hack" to make it work.

Comment: Check out the second answer here from @ErickPetru : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381446/center-html-input-text-field-placeholder Looks like it can be done for specific browsers. Your CSS should already do the trick:
`.centerText{
    text-align: center;
}`

Comment: You can also try using `padding-left` to pad the left side and push the text toward the center. Not very clean or fluid, yet it will do the trick in more browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here some tinkering from your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/jb8Jx/2/ Just shows you some ways to try and move the placeholder about.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>    
    <section id="home" data-role="page">
        <header data-role="header">
            <h1>test page</h1>
        </header>
        <div data-role="content">
                <label>Left Align</label><input type="text" placeholder="email" class="leftText">
            <label>Right Align</label><input type="text" placeholder="email" class="rightText">
            <label>Center Text</label><input type="text" placeholder="email" class="centerText">
            <label>Pad Left</label><input type="text" placeholder="email" class="leftPadText">
            </div>
        <div data-role="popup" id="popupLogin" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all">
            <h3 class="centerText">Register free!</h3>

            <div class="popup">
                <form>                
                      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="centerText" placeholder="email" data-theme="a" style="text-align: center;"/>
                      <button type="submit" data-theme="b">Sign me up</button>

                      <p class="centerText">
                          text1<br/>
                          text2<br/>
                          etc...<br/>
                      </p>                
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
input.centerText{
    text-align: center;
}


input.leftText {
    text-align: left;
}

input.rightText {
    text-align: right;
}

input.leftPadText {
    padding-left: 220px;
}
```