# Background text in input type text php

Tags: php, text, background, textfield

I think its a easy question, but i dont know how to search this question in google

I need a background text in a input-text field. Like: Insert Your Name. And when i press in to the field to insert my name, the text disappears

So here's my code now..

```php
<textarea id="dox" name="<?php echo $_SESSION["dox"]; ?>" rows="25" cols="80">hello type here.</textarea><br />
```

Can anyone help me? Add everything whats needed... thanks alot <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the placeholder attribute:

```
<textarea id="dox" name="<?php echo $_SESSION["dox"]; ?>" rows="25" cols="80" placeholder="hello type here."></textarea>
```

Comment: Hi man, thanks alot! So i've changed the placeholder text to "Name". But i want the the text to be in the middle of the placeholder? Currently it looks like this.. https://gyazo.com/a2faf51cd6bae5b16987347f24bc230f

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381446/center-html-input-text-field-placeholder

Answer (score 1):

For textarea and input fields you can simply use the "placeholder" attribute like this:

```
<textarea placeholder="hello type here." id="dox" name="<?php echo $_SESSION["dox"]; ?>" rows="25" cols="80"></textarea>
```

However, this attribute is not compatible with all (mainly old) Browsers. 
If you want to reach those browsers you can use a JQuery Plugin like this for example: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

Or use javascript with onfocus and onblur events like this:

```
<textarea onfocus="if(this.value=='Placeholder text')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Placeholder text';">Placeholder text</textarea>
```

Comment: Hi man, thanks alot! So i've changed the placeholder text to "Name". But i want the the text to be in the middle of the placeholder? Currently it looks like this.. https://gyazo.com/a2faf51cd6bae5b16987347f24bc230f

Comment: Use CSS to center align the text in the input text field.