# How Make The Placeholder text centered in Semantic Ui textbox/input

Tags: semantic-ui

In semantic-ui, how can I place the placeholder text (name in below example) in the center of the input box, instead of it being aligned to the left?

`<input type="text" placeholder="name" class="?">`

Comment: You must create and CSS style. It can't be done directly from Semantic. You can find an example here [Center HTML Input Text Field Placeholder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381446/center-html-input-text-field-placeholder)