# Vertically align an input placeholder with CSS (or set line-height)

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to vertically align a placeholder independently of the parent input? There seems to be no way to have the placeholder in the code below appear in the vertical center of the input field. I've tried all css properties and workarounds I can think of or find online but the different font sizes on the input and the placeholder seem to make it impossible in webkit browsers at least.

**Edit:** Left is the issue, right is the desired look:
[image]

```css
input {
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 44px;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-size: 9px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #AAA;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' placeholder='enter some text' />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center HTML Input Text Field Placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381446/center-html-input-text-field-placeholder)

Comment: @Chang. They are totally different

Comment: Set the line-height and font-size same for input works fine for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best solution out there might be to simply add a `translate3d` transform to the placeholder CSS rule as follows:

```css
input {
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 44px;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-size: 9px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #AAA;
  transform:translate3d(0,-4px,0)
}
```

```html
<input type='text' placeholder='enter some text' />
```

Answer (score 7):

This feels like such a stupid "solution", but maybe you could substitute `transform:scale(0.45)` in place of the `font-size: 9px;`.  It seems to work just about anywhere `font-size` in `::-webkit-input-placeholder` is supported.

```css
input {
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 44px;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #AAA;
  transform: scale(0.45);
}
```

```html
<input type='text' placeholder='enter some text' />
```

## Edit: Left Aligned

```css
input {
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 44px;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #AAA;
  transform: scale(0.45);
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' placeholder='enter some text' />
```

Comment: oh I love it! So hacky and looks perfect! Thank you!!

Comment: @cronoklee lol Glad you're happy about it.  It just makes me feel dirty.

Comment: Don't know about you but it ain't vertically centered, or I should say it like this, it can't be done.

Comment: This solution doesnt work when input is left aligned. Trying to find a workaround now...

Comment: @cronoklee It can with a tweak.  just set the transform to be left center with `transform-origin: 0% 50%;`.

Comment: Thanks @JosephMarikle. In trying to solve the left align issue, I discovered that this actually works too and you can leave the font-size the same: `transform:translate3d(0,-4px,0)`. Would you feel any less dirty with that approach?  :D

Comment: @cronoklee Yeah, actually.  I don't like the thought of using a transform to mimic native browser font scaling.  It's unfortunate it has to use a fixed value like 4px rather than relative units, but I feel like this approach is the lesser of two evils.  That solution should probably be posted as a new answer.

Comment: Okay posted as a new answer. Thanks again for the help mate