# how to align date input placeholder to the center on firefox

Tags: html, css, date, firefox, alignment

I wonder why I can't align date inputs placeholders to the center in ***firefox***?

```css
input{
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<input type="date">
```

Comment: Is this question / answers useful? >>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381446/center-html-input-text-field-placeholder

Answer (score 0):

The text-align is working, as you could see the text reverting back to the original place when you remove text-align.

If you are asking why the text is not placed at the middle of the input field, well, the white space isn't exactly empty. There are invisible elements within the input that are occupying the right side of the input field. Therefore, the placeholder text won't appear aligned to the center in the default size.

If you give make the input field big enough, then you could see the `text-align` working.

```css
input{
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<input type="date">
```